# Why is my print function delayed?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm really struggling to understand why it's not working the way I think it should.

**Edit:** Sorry for any confusion, it is the first `print` that will not execute. `print('The alarm will sound at ' + result, flush=True)`

Nothing happens until `if time.strftime('%H:%M') == result` is True. No matter where I put the print function, it will not run until the above is met. Even inside the `while` loop, it **will not** run.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import argparse
import time
import datetime

def alarm(set_time):

    set_time = str(set_time)[:2]+ ':' + str(set_time)[2:]
    alarm_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(set_time,'%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M')
    return alarm_time

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('wake', help='The time for the alarm to sound', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    result = alarm(args.wake)
    print('The alarm will sound at ' + result, flush=True)

    while True:

        if time.strftime('%H:%M') == result:
            print('Wake up')
            return
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Isn't that the idea? I mean... Nothing is going to happen until the current time matches the time the alarm is gonna sound at? Dunno... Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Hang on; are you saying that the alarm doesn't activate at the specified time, or that it only activates at the specified time?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about the second `print`. Rewording. 

It's the first `print` that doesn't execute until the aforementioned is True.

Comment: What sort of environment are you running this program in?  Some weird environment, that doesn't handle I/O buffering in the normal way, seems the only possible explanation.

Comment: Lol @jasonharper.

I was running from Git Bash.

Comment: On Windows then? Your script prints immediately on my linux machine so can't duplicate there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the change below. It's work fine.

```
import argparse
import time
import datetime

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('wake', help='The time for the alarm to sound', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()


    time_part = args.wake.split(':')

    d = datetime.datetime.now()

    wake_time = datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day, int(time_part[0]), int(time_part[1]), 0, 0)


    print('The alarm will sound at ' + args.wake, flush=True)

    while True:

        if datetime.datetime.now() > wake_time:
            print('Wake up')
            return
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: OP's code works fine on my machine - as far as the print is concerned at least. Not sure how this solves that problem.

Comment: Nick Bonne, maybe you can try force another print on else. Something like that `print('', end='')`. The `print('The alarm will sound at ' + args.wake, flush=True)` ever works for me.